# Removing a layout in android dynamically?

Tags: android-layout

I am working in android.  i wanted to cleara layout each time i press a button and start everything again(as in doing "Reset") . Its not working with the following code.

```
 final TableLayout rel=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab1);
int k=rel.getChildCount();
                    System.out.print("k is"+k);
                                for(int x=0;x<k; x++)
                          {
                             View v1 = rel.getChildAt(x);
                            rel.removeView(v1);

                         }
```

So i tried to print the value of k and i got it like 0101100 where i expected an integer. Any help is appreciated ..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rel.removeAllViews(); helped me

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it invisible

```
v1.setVisibility(int)
```